# Parsing nodes with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing web pages and I want to get the link from the `<img src>` by finding the `<div id="image">`.

How do I do this in Nokogiri? I tried walking through the child nodes but it fails.

```
<div id="image" class="image textbox ">
  <div class="">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="" original-title="">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("site.com"))

doc.css("div.image").each do |node|

    node.children().each do |c|

    puts c.attr("src")
    end     

end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the failure you get? What's the code you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works for you

```
require 'nokogiri'

source = <<-HTML
 <div id="image" class="image textbox ">
   <div class="">
     <img src="img.jpg" alt="" original-title="">
   </div>
 </div>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(source)

doc.css('div#image > div > img').each do |image|
  puts image.attr('src')
end
```

Output:

```
img.jpg
```

Comment: That worked great! I have to take a closer look at the css method. Thanks :)

Comment: quick question, how do i quickly convert the value i got to a string so i can manipulate it? edit: found out you just use the method text on the object. txt = img.text

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great resource: http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Modifying an example a bit, I get this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("site.com"))

doc.css("div.image img").each do |img|

    puts img.attr("src")

end
```

Although you should use the ID selector, `#image`, rather than the class selector, `.image`, when you can. It is very much faster.